# Ambiguous match found for 'FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1[UserForLoginDto] FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult Validate(UserForLoginDto)'

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I just have started to dotnet adventure and I stuck at one point that is related with autofac and fluentvalidation extension.
I have custom extention to validate like java spring anotation.
I have tested my code and I ensure that validation doesn't work at the moment.

**Here is my custom validation extension**

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using Core.CrossCuttingConcerns.Validation;
using Core.Utilities.Interceptors;
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Core.Aspects.Autofac.Validation
{
    public class ValidationAspect : MethodInterception //Aspect
    {
        private Type _validatorType;
        public ValidationAspect(Type validatorType)
        {
            //defensive coding
            if (!typeof(IValidator).IsAssignableFrom(validatorType))
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Bu bir doğrulama sınıfı değil");
            }

            _validatorType = validatorType;
        }
        protected override void OnBefore(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(_validatorType);
            var entityType = _validatorType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var entities = invocation.Arguments.Where(t => t.GetType() == entityType);
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                ValidationTool.Validate(validator, entity);
            }
        }

        
    }
}
```

**Here is my UserValidator**

```
using Core.Entities.Concrete;
using Entities.DTOs;
using FluentValidation;

namespace Business.ValidationRules.FluentValidation
{
    public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<UserForLoginDto>
    {
        public UserValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(u => u.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress();
            RuleFor(u => u.Password).NotEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my UserForLoginDto**

```
using Core.Entities;

namespace Entities.DTOs
{
    public class UserForLoginDto : IDto
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Here is my usage in the AuthController**

```
[HttpPost("login")]
[ValidationAspect(typeof(UserValidator))]
public IResult Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
{
    var userToLogin = _authService.Login(userForLoginDto);
    if (!userToLogin.Success)
    {
        return new ErrorResult(userToLogin.Message);
    }

    var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(userToLogin.Data);
    if (result.Success)
    {
        userToLogin.Data.Token = result.Data;
        return new SuccessDataResult<User>(userToLogin.Data);
    }

    return new ErrorResult(result.Message);
    
}
```

I have basically tried:

- adding dependencies by hardcoded like using UserValidator
- adding dependencies by automatic detection using autofac
- changing AbstractValidator to AbstractValidator

None of them worked and I made a research a little bit but I couldn't find anything
Also, it doesn't return anything related validation I tried in my postman and swagger also.